# Spring MapFactoryBean

Tags: java, spring

I am new to spring. Can I edit a List from a mapfactoryBean after it was initialized?

example
I have List of roles

1. Admin
2. Assistant Admin

Can i edit this list when my `actionlistener`-->`contextInitialized` is executed? I want to add the role `Secretary`